# Proper Optional Parameters in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

If the value of @param is null, which is better to use:

1. `WHERE t.column = COALESCE(@param, '')`
2. `WHERE t.column = IFNULL(@param, '')`
3. `WHERE (@param IS NULL OR t.column = @param)`

Is the OR more expensive than comparing the column to a value that will return all values for the specified column?  My understanding is that options 1 & 2 will force a full table scan every time, while #3 would not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 is best because the optimizer will short-circuit that evaluation during the optimizer stage and eliminate the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying the three options, using `EXPLAIN` in front of your query and see what MySQL thinks as it relates to your table and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 looks like a syntax error; ISNULL only takes one parameter, and returns a boolean.

Options 1 and 3 could return different values.  When @param is null, option 1 would return only rows where t.column is the empty string, where option 3 would return all rows.  Either one would use a full table scan unless you have an index on t.column; even then, option 3 would use the full scan when @param is null.

Comment: Why do you believe option 3 would perform a full table scan if @param were to be null?  It would pass the first half of the test; the second part shouldn't be executed.

Comment: I guess it wouldn't exactly "scan" the full table so much as return the entire thing.  Is that what you want?

Comment: With IFNULL, options 1 and 2 should be basically identical.  There might be some performance difference, but it should be negligible.

Comment: I want to return records with any t.column value if the @param is null.

Comment: In that case, option 3 does exactly what you want.  There are ways to make something like 1 and 2 do the same thing, but not as efficiently.